# How can I dynamically replace parts of a .svg file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, create-react-app

I am importing a svg file to use as an image in my project. The svg file has a color in it that I want to change to my own color (which is not known ahead of time). I realize getSourceCode and setSourceCode are not real methods but I used them to hopefully demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish.

```
import React from "react";
import emptyOrderImage from "./images/illustrations/empty_order.svg";

function CurrentOrder(props) {
  // Trying to get svg source code as string
  let svgSourceCodeString = emptyOrderImage.getSourceCode();

  // Assume the new color was dynamically loaded
  const newColor = "#FAFAFA";

  // I am trying to replace all occurences of #FFA500 with the new color
  const newSourceCode = originalSourceCode.replace(/#FFA500/gi, newColor);

  // Now I need to set svg to new source code
  emptyOrderImage.setSourceCode(newSourceCode);

  return (
    <div style={{ flex: "display", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <img src={emptyOrderImage} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CurrentOrder;
```

Comment: Use `fill` to change the colour of an svg.

Comment: easier just to write each individual tag as a react SFC then dynamically render then as you would normally use react IMO

Comment: @Kobe there are multiple fill in svg source, not all of them I want to replace. I only want to replace certain color (#FFA500).

Comment: @DanielLizik it is a bit tricky because I am using multiple svg illustrations that I download online, so it would take some effort to have to always add new illustration if I were to create SFC for each tag. It is why I thought simply replacing hex would be the easiest solution (less maintenance)

Comment: @user3614030 https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr

Comment: @DanielLizik that looks very promising, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create `svg.js` file in your project and insert all your SVG files with jsx format code like below:

```
// svg.js

export const HomeSvgIcon = () => {/* svg code */}

export const MenuSvgIcon = () => {/* svg code */}
```

You should just get the SVG code of each SVG and put in [this site](https://svg2jsx.herokuapp.com/) and get jsx format of your SVG code.

Now you can modify all SVG props with react. for example, an SVG code can have multi `fill` prop that you can get it from the prop.

**Demo**

[image: Edit mystifying-water-8orxh]

Answer (score 0):

If you render SVG into DOM as @MohammadReza Khedri suggested, you can style the SVG using CSS variables.